# A javascript file not working anymore

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file containing some basic form validation codes.I call the said javascript file from my php page by calling it like

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="javascript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
```

just above the closing  tag.Now the weird thing is that up until yesterday the javascript file was working great but today its no longer working.The validation codes inside the .js file don't get executed.No changes have been made in the said .js file.Has anybody faced such an issue.If yes then please let me know the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the console output when you load the page?

Comment: Do you have document.ready in forms.js file?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add the contents of the JS file.

Comment: is the relative path correct ? any error or 404 in console ?

Comment: Any particular browser or all of them?

Comment: their might be some worm entered into your code last night and ate html tags

Comment: @Mahi - assuming the code was stored on an Apple :p

Comment: @JaromandaX blackberry can be too :D

Comment: Guys thanks for the quick response.@Sven pointed me in the right direction. Its been not working because i had been using an undefined variable in a 'If' statement.